Why my Bootstrap tabs don't show the content added with easyui datagrid?
I am creating a website using the bootstrap nav-tabs, I'm creating two tabs and this tabs showing a table list of candidates, but when i click the other tabs("Entry Form TTD" tab) the content in it is not showing/blank
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column border border-danger">
        <div class="container my-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="candidateTabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="nav-link active" id="lolos-interview-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#lolos-interview" role="tab" aria-controls="lolos-interview" aria-selected="true">Lolos Interview</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="nav-link" id="entry-form-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#entry-form" role="tab" aria-controls="entry-form" aria-selected="false">Entry Form TTD</button>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content" id="candidateTabsContent">
                <!-- Lolos Interview Tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="lolos-interview" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="lolos-interview-tab">
                    <div class="panel datagrid easyui-fluid my-3 border border-danger table-responsive">
                        <table id="tableCandidate" class="easyui-datagrid" style="max-height:610px; min-height:610px; width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="30%" align="center" data-options="field:'fname', sortable:true">Nama</th>
                                    <th width="10%" align="center" data-options="field:'gender'">Jenis Kelamin</th>
                                    <th width="10%" align="center" data-options="field:'age', sortable:true">Usia</th>
                                    <th width="10%" align="center" data-options="field:'religion'">Agama</th>
                                    <th width="10%" align="center" data-options="field:'marital'">Pernikahan</th>
                                    <th width="20%" align="center" data-options="field:'education'">Pendidikan Terakhir</th>
                                    <th width="20%" align="center" data-options="field:'experience'">Pengalaman Kerja</th>
                                    <th width="20%" align="center" data-options="field:'note'">Catatan</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Sudah TTD Entry Form Tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="entry-form" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="entry-form-tab">
                    <div class="panel datagrid easyui-fluid my-3 border border-danger table-responsive">
                        <table id="signCandidate" class="easyui-datagrid" style="max-height:610px; min-height:610px; width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="30%" align="center" data-options="field:'fname', sortable:true">Nama</th>
                                    <th width="10%" align="center" data-options="field:'gender'">Jenis Kelamin</th>
                                    <th width="10%" align="center" data-options="field:'age', sortable:true">Usia</th>
                                    <th width="10%" align="center" data-options="field:'religion'">Agama</th>
                                    <th width="10%" align="center" data-options="field:'marital'">Pernikahan</th>
                                    <th width="20%" align="center" data-options="field:'education'">Pendidikan Terakhir</th>
                                    <th width="20%" align="center" data-options="field:'experience'">Pengalaman Kerja</th>
                                    <th width="20%" align="center" data-options="field:'note'">Catatan</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Initialize datagrid for showing candidates
        $(function() {
            $('#tableCandidate').datagrid({
                url: 'includes/display.php',
                singleSelect: true,
                remoteSort: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                pagination: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                nowrap: false,
                remoteFilter: true,
                onClickRow: onRowClick
            });

            $('#signCandidate').datagrid({
                url: 'includes/submit.php',
                singleSelect: true,
                remoteSort: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                pagination: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                nowrap: false,
                remoteFilter: true,
                onClickRow: onRowClick
            });
        });
        // Function to handle row click
        function onRowClick(index, row) {
            if (row.id) {  // Ensure the row has an id
                window.location.href = 'entry.php?id=' + row.id;
            } else {
                console.error("Row ID is missing.");
            }
        }
    </script>

the result when clicking the tabs is like this:
entry form ttd tab
but when i tried open the devtools, or zoom out/in the screen page, the table is showing:
entry form ttd tab when opening the devtools
proof that the table is showing the data but need to open the devtools to show it
I already tried timeout for the screen, changing the style, or using .datagrid('reload') function, but it still not solve my problem.
SOLVED
thank to c3roe, by adding the resize method into Bootstrap shown.bs.tab event, the data is shown:
$('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var targetTab = $(e.target).attr("data-bs-target");
  if (targetTab === "#lolos-interview") {
     $('#tableCandidate').datagrid('resize');
  } else if (targetTab === "#entry-form") {
     $('#signCandidate').datagrid('resize');
  }
});


i dont think its tab issue. could you verify data is coming from includes/submit.php

@KesavanR well yes, the data is coming from includes/submit.php, it get the data perfectly fine, but i still have the issues that the tabs is blank, i add new proof in my question where the data is showing but need open the devtools to display it.

try removing bs data attributes, i.e. have both tables outside of bs tabs, visible from the start and see what happens

Likely very much a tabs issue. The library probably tries to read the dimensions of certain elements, when it initializes itself, to figure out how it has to render its content. But it will not be able to do that, for anything within a tab that is hidden at this moment - because that hiding happens via display: none, and that means there are no element dimensions to read, for that element and any descendants it contains. Once you have the tab open, and then resize or open dev tools, that will probably fire a resize event handler, which makes it go through that process again.

It has a resize method, description "Do resize and do layout." https://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php#methods You should hook into Bootstrap's shown.bs.tab event (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navs-tabs/#events), and explicitly call that resize method from there, then it should work.

@C3roe thanks for the solution, i did like you said and it does work for me now
